# Design pattern for response parser

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a method which would make an API call, after getting the response, it parses the response and then return the result. For the parse response part, I used a private method `getBookListFromResponse` to do. My concern is that the parse response part won't be reusable in other places (if in case in the future) as it's a private method. Is there any design guidance regarding how best to implement parsing response ?

```
public interface QueryBookService {
  List<String> getBookName(String authorName);
}

@Service
public class QueryBookServiceImpl implements QueryBookService {

  @Autowired
  private BookAPI bookAPI;

  @Override
  public List<String> getBookName(String authorName) {
    QueryBookRequest request = createQueryBookRequest(authorName);

    QueryBookResponse response = bookAPI.queryBook(queryBookRequest);

    return getBookListFromResponse(response); 
  }

  private List<String> getBookListFromResponse(QueryBookResponse response) {
    //implementation
}

  private QueryBookRequest createQueryBookRequest(String authorName) {
    //implementation
  }
}
```

Comment: Create a separate class and extend that class

Comment: Use just Mapper pattern

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your post is that you wish to make the 'getBookListFromResponse' method reusable such that other parts of the application could use it. Though this on a large part depends on the logical structure of your design. Usually, separating the method in a helper class (if it is to be used from same package) or a separate 'util' package, if it will be used by the same library or a separate library, if it is to be used from rest of your application would achieve the result you are looking for.

The above is a very general treatment, the specifics would of course depend on many other design aspects, like would the behaviour need to be inherited etc.